# "laravel Migration Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I have a problem In Laravel and I do not know where the problem is. someone can help me . And thank you in advance.
I have two tables (clients, and reparations)
I want to make a foreign key with the string field ('cin_client'), when I create the table reparations it does not work anymore
/* ************* table clients **************>

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateClientsTable extends Migration
{
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id_client');
            $table->string('nom_client');
            $table->string('prenom_client'); 
            $table->string('adresse_client'); 
            $table->string('tel_client'); 
            $table->string('cin_client',30); 

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('clients');
    }
}
```

/************* Table reparations *************/

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateReparationsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reparations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id_reparation');
            $table->string('type_reparation')->nullable();
            $table->string('date_reparation')->nullable();
            $table->integer('prix_reparation')->nullable();
            $table->string('genre_marque_type')->nullable();

            $table->boolean('etat_reparation')->nullable(); 

/*$table->foreign('client_cin')->references('cin_client')->on('clients');*/
            $table->timestamps();
$table->string('client_cin',30);
        });

        Schema::table('reparations', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('client_cin')->references('cin_client')->on('clients');

        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('reparations');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$table->string('client_cin')->unsigned();` You can't have an unsigned string. Unsigned is for number types

Answer (score 0):

So, that database error almost always means that the column you've defined to hold the foreign key reference in the first table, and the column you've defined in the second table are not matching formats or lengths. Looking at the migration (and not being sure what DBS you're using) I think you need to remove `->unsigned()` from the column definition for reparations.client_cin.